# How are IP packets routed from LAN to WAN?

Tags: iptables, router, linux-networking, switch, openwrt

I have OpenWRT set up on a router, with a wireless client connected on the LAN, and connected to another network on the WAN. `wlan1` is bridged on the `br-lan` interface, and typically forwards to the LAN interface `eth0`.

I'm currently sending TCP/UDP packets from a client (`192.168.1.20`) on the LAN to a server (`128.112.94.34`) on the WAN. When I run `tcpdump -len -i br-lan` (viewing the packets on the `br-lan` interface, I can see each of these packets coming through, something like:

```
22:12:03.055370 58:7f:57:0c:e4:80 > c0:56:27:72:a3:5b, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 73: 192.168.1.20.49437 > 128.112.94.34.12341: Flags [P.], seq 105:112, ack 1, win 4117, options [nop,nop,TS val 581515569 ecr 1500229582], length 7
22:12:04.055378 58:7f:57:0c:e4:80 > c0:56:27:72:a3:5b, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 73: 192.168.1.20.49437 > 128.112.94.34.12341: Flags [P.], seq 112:119, ack 1, win 4117, options [nop,nop,TS val 581516566 ecr 1500230581], length 7
22:12:05.042628 58:7f:57:0c:e4:80 > c0:56:27:72:a3:5b, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 73: 192.168.1.20.49437 > 128.112.94.34.12341: Flags [P.], seq 119:126, ack 1, win 4117, options [nop,nop,TS val 581517541 ecr 1500231577], length 7
```

However, when I run the command on `eth0` (`tcpdump -len -i eth0`), I get none of the lines above. I've checked my firewall (allowing all connections from LAN to WAN already), route table (`192.168.1.x` routes to the default gateway), and nothing obvious to me is preventing this.

My question is: **How does the linux kernel route packets from `br-lan` to `eth0` on a router?**

What kinds of subsystems or authentication mechanisms does a router go through to let a packet pass through?

Answer (score 1):

Bridging and routing are not the same. Bridging happens at a lower layer than routing. Essentially bridging behaves like a switch. The virtual switch implemented by the Linux bridging code will have one interface attached to the upper layers of the network stack as well as a number of physical interfaces. So in your case where there are two physical interfaces in the bridge, it means you have a virtual 3-port switch.

Packets send to a known MAC address are only send to the interface the MAC address is known to be attached to - this is crucial for performance reasons. So when the switch receive a packet on `wlan1` with destination MAC `c0:56:27:72:a3:5b` which the virtual switch knows is attached to the `br-lan` interface, it will bridge that packet from `wlan1` to `br-lan`. That way it will never touch the `eth0` interface.